# Why is Google not accepting my phone number?

Tags: google-account

I'm trying to create a Google account but I fail the verification. The problem is that I get this message:

> This phone number format is not recognized. Please check the country and number.

I have selected United States as my country and the number is in this form: +153390XXXXX. I have also tried entering the number in the form 53390XXXXX.

Comment: Try `+(1)(533)(90XXXXX)`. You are halfway between two formats.

Comment: Also try `00153390XXXXX`

Comment: none of the above work..i get the same message. This f-in incredible...anybody know how i can contact google?

Comment: Why are you using the 1 prefix at all? Have you tried using just `53390XXXXX`, `533-90X-XXXX`, or `(533) 90X-XXXX`?

Comment: I have used all possible formats. The problem SEEMS to be that google does not accept 533 as area code; i used another number with a different area code and it was accepted (and i used the +1AAAXXXXXXX form)

Comment: Possibly because 533 is a ["non-geographic" area code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_500,_533_and_544). It's not tied to a particular place and so they won't use it to verify you.